# Mathjax takes time to load data in android

Tags: android, mathjax

I am working on an android app in which I have used mathview library which is based on mathjax. When I click on a button to view data it takes time to load data due to mathjax as it is slow. Is there any way that I can avoid this or any way in which I can display an image for a specific time(which is expected time to load data) and data loads in background and then after the specified time, it switches to the desired activity. I have searched and got to know about asynctask. But I am new to android development and couldn't understand how to use it to make my app more fast.

Comment: Does it take a long time each time you load it, or are consecutive uses faster?

Comment: Each time it takes a long time.

Comment: Then I advise you to reuse your WebView after the first ime you load the library.